# RPM build, can I change gsettings in %post?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec

After installing an rpm package that I built I would like to change some gsettings. I tried doing so in the `%post` section, but it does not do anything during the install (not even fail).

spec file:

```
...
%post
echo "test post"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'something-else'
```

The echo works, and if I manually type the gsettings command into the terminal it works, but during the installation the command does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about `gsettings` but don't forget that `rpm` will install/run as root. Can you `sudo gsettings ...` the command? I _think_ it is going to change the GNOME settings for the _root user_, not you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron is correct in their comment: Even if you can successfully run `gsettings` in your `%post` script, you'll be changing settings for the `root` user.

If you want to change configurations for some other user in an automated fashion, you could drop a script into `/etc/profile.d`; these scripts are run for new login shells, which will include someone logging into an X session.

You would want to add some conditionals around your `gsettings` statement to ensure that it only runs successfully once: if it runs on every login, you've made it impossible for someone to undo this particular configuration change, which can be a frustrating experience.

I would argue that this is better solved via documentation ("After installing this package, here's how to activate the new cursor theme...").

Comment: I decided to go against pure documentation, because right now changing a theme in gnome requires either the terminal or gnome-tweaks, both of which should not be a requirement for a regular user.

The script in profile.d approach sounds promising, I might try that. If so, I will need to create some flag somewhere. Is there a good place for this (I have seen peole putting ".hiddenfiles" into $HOME, but I would REALLY like to avoid that).

Comment: Likely locations (based on their descriptions [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)) would be `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (aka `$HOME/.config`) or `$XDG_STATE_HOME` (aka `$HOME/.local/state`).